# Getting crash in UINavigation from one view to another view of same class,How to solve it?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

In my project, having some 10 view controllers. In one of the view controller I added one more view controller in xib to provide extra functionality(one actual view + added viewcontroller for the single class).When I tried to move ie.navigate from its actaul view to added view controller, for the first time its navigating fine and also come back to the actual view.But if again I go that added view controller my app getting crash.This is the error shown.

```
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported (<UIViewController: 0xc09e460>)'
First throw call stack:
(0x30da012 0x28b4e7e 0xb9c5b0 0xb9c098 0xa7f3f 0xab327 0x28c86b0 0x5fcfb 0x28c86b0 0x706035 0x305df3f 0x305d96f 0x3080734 0x307ff44 0x307fe1b 0x33127e3 0x3312668 0xaa265c 0x719d 0x2685) 
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception"
```

And the method action I used in the code is

```
- ( void ) move {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:addedviewController animated:YES];
}
```

Also I added the screenshot...[image]

Comment: what strategy you are using to come back?

Comment: just disconnect your IBOutlet connection and reconnect it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add an instance of viewcontroller that is already on the stack. Why don't you pop controllers off stack until you get the addedViewController instance?

Comment: From the crash, log it's clear that you are pushing a viewcontroller more than ones. Before pushing the same viewcontroller. You will need to pop view controllers. Check this out http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popViewControllerAnimated:

Comment: Also Explain me the use case a little more in detail as I didn't get enough from your question except for the crash log..

Comment: Can u pls take a look of the image.when i click the checkout btn(firstview),it should navigate to the next page.

Comment: can u paste the codes that are getting executed on clicking of checkout button(first view) and the code that executes on clicking of back button (next page)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24520/discussion-between-shashank-and-venkatesh)

Answer (score 0):

if you create another object?

```
AddedviewControllerClass *addedviewControllerTemp = [[AddedviewControllerClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourXib.xib"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:addedviewControllerTemp animated:YES];

[addedviewControllerTemp release] //if not ARC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use to add your `ViewController`

```
[self presentViewController:yourView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

To remove

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```